# How to resume an aborted Ubuntu upgrade from 16 to 18 lts during sudo do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, 18.04, updates, do-release-upgrade

This is the scenario.
I started upgrading from 16 to 18 with  sudo do-release-upgrade.
After sometime my wifi connectivity got lost.
About 56% of installation was complete before the process got aborted when internet stopped.
Now how can I resume the process so as to not to start again from the 
beginning ?
NOTE-I didn't yet reboot my system yet neither closed the particular terminal. Any  quick fixes ? So request quick help while my system is running.
*I read somewhere about this  `sudo screen -D -r` but it shows **sudo: screen: command not found***

Comment: `screen` is used to re-attached to a lost session  (-r = reattach) which is not your issue.  I would suggest just `do-release-upgrade` again.  With luck it should detect where it is, and continue.

Comment: 56% of the whole process or the downloading part or the installation part?  I guess you don't have a problem with your system and you just don't want to waste time downloading again?  Indeed, guiverc is correct...just run `do-release-upgrade` again and it will continue where it left off.

Comment: yes thanks now it works as @guiverc told to do .

Answer (score 0):

For me this always works well.

`sudo apt-get update -y` [then it always error about last process is not complete]

then whatever process was not yet completed, I do ->

`rm -rf /.../.../lock` [replace ... with process that locked]

`rm -rf /..../.../.../` [replace ... with step was not succeed]

Then I run again

`sudo apt-get update -y` [if no error]

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Usually it starts from last success process but sometimes with luck way back from me, I need to start all over again.

Please not try this on live server. I have no confident this is ultimate guide.